Best method to create stable solution in analog computer using op-amps
As a beginner in electronics and engaged primarily in mathematics, naturally I'd like to explore the wonderful world of analog computing. As my first attempt, I have created the following circuit designed to solve the system
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
x'(t) &= \phantom - y(t) \\ 
y'(t) &= -x(t)
\end{aligned}
\right. 
$$
which is basically a harmonic oscillator \$\ x''(t) = -x(t)\$:
 

What I get from it is a damped oscillation at the frequency 1/(2RC), so my question is: What is the soundest way to have this enter a stable mode in which it oscillates indefinitely at the solution of the differential equation?
My first instinct would be to at a potentiometer in series with R25 in the inverter to interactively create a smidgen of gain making up for the losses in the circuit, and fiddle with it until the circuit oscillates stably. Does that make sense?

Well, it's difficult to physically realize an analog linear system with poles exactly on the jw axis.  Typically, you need a nonlinear element or some other feedback mechanism to prevent the output from increasing to saturation (or conversely decaying to zero).  The first HP audio generators used a tungsten light bulb as the nonlinear element to generate a very low distortion sine wave, but there are other techniques like AGC, etc.  You could potentially adjust the gain by hand with a pot until it seems to be stable, but any temperature change or drift could result in saturation or decay.

I was hoping the nontrivial solution would be a stable attractor for the system. "The Art of Electronics" implements a Lorentz attractor using integrators and signal multipliers, and they show a picture of their oscillograph output. In any case, slowing the decay down would already do the trick for starters.

Right, there are various implementations of the Lorentz attractor, but as you point out they typically require an analog multiplier.  It's one way to do it though.

For reference, here is an oscillator that uses a non-linear element for automatic gain control (negative feedback)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_bridge_oscillator

did you simulate or build with hardware?

@RussellH Both. I think, learning what I just learned, my next implementation will be a damped oscillator (so what's happening is actually supposed to happen and I can fiddle with the parameters) and once my signal multipliers come, I'll try to implement Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model, which should have a stable periodic solution.
I think in my mind I was hoping it'd converge like Picard iteration does.

The circuit that you have should provide an oscillation, but only is an initial voltage exists on one or both of the integrating capacitors. If one volt initial voltage exists on one of them, then the output should have steady oscillation at 1 volt peak. The voltage amplitude will either rise or fall over time minutes or hours if done right. Adjusting the loop gain will not help much with stabilizing the amplitude. it will affect the frequency. ...continued

@RussellH Very grateful! The actual physical circuit does provide an initial oscillation when the power is connected: the bigger the capacitor (the lower the frequency), the longer it swings -- but gradually to zero.

@RussellH - may I ask you why you think that the signal amplitude will be 1V peak? I am sure that - for equal time constants - both integrators will reach the limits determined by the supply voltages (however, only with a small clipping effect). The signal quality can be drastically improved for two different time constants.

@Matthias As you are "a beginner in electronics" I like to point tthe fact that the opamps in your circuit need, of course, two supply voltages (plus/minus). I mention this because you gave no corresponding information.

I noticed an error in my previous comment, "is" should be "if". The circuit that you have should provide an oscillation, but only if an initial voltage exists on one or both of the integrating capacitors. If one volt initial voltage exists on one of them, then the output should have steady oscillation at 1 volt peak. The voltage amplitude will either rise or fall over time minutes or hours if done right. Adjusting the loop gain will not help much with stabilizing the amplitude. it will affect the frequency.

@LvW: " may I ask you why you think that the signal amplitude will be 1V peak"|| 1. I solved the OP's equation. Read my answer. 2. I simulated the equation using analog computer techniques in LTspice. Read my answer. 3) I have observed this in actual hardware.

@LvW: "I am sure that - for equal time constants - both integrators will reach the limits determined by the supply voltages (however, only with a small clipping effect)" || Your assuming that the circuit is inherently unstable. It is actual slightly stable but very underdamped. Read my answer. I provide a mechanism that will make the system unstable so  using VCC as the amplitude takes over from the initial conditions.

@LvW:"The signal quality can be drastically improved for two different time constants."|| Perhaps. That is a refinement that is for another question. This question is about using an analog computer to solve an equation. It did not work for the OP. My answer shows how to make it work, what he was missing. In this context, different time constants only change the frequency calculation. $\omega^{2}_{n}=A/ \sqrt{R1C1R2C2}$.

@RussellH OK, but you have assumed ideal opamps, correct? As I have mentioned already, real oscillators (and simulation with real opamps) will always show rising amplitudes (loop gain magnitude>0 dB at 0deg phase crossing) with (small) clipping effects due to supply rails. More than that, initial voltages are NOT required due to the power switch-on transients. Last Question: Did you really observe continuous oscillation (1V) below supply rail limiting for actual hardware realization ? I would be surprised.

@RussellH - I am an engineer. Therefore, I see the system under discussion from the realization point of view - and not from the mathematical aspects only. Of course, in math I can define ideal integrators and also an ideal unity loop gain.  On the other hand, the TO did not use ideal opamp models, but real TL081 models. This made me think that he perhaps had a hardware realization in mind.

@LvW:"OK, but you have assumed ideal opamps, correct?"|| The equation to be solved was provided by the OP. It assumes an ideal system. I use real op-amps in simulation, then explain why the system does not work. The title indicates the question is about analog computers, not oscillators. This is a first example.

@RussellH I only can repeat that I have seen the circuit from the practical (engineering) point of view. As it seems that was my fault. But the circuit shown by the TO is an oscillator. It has no inputs for usage as an analog computer. As an open-loop circuit it would represent one of the known state-variable filter topologies.

@LVW: The equation has no inputs either. But it still has a solution.

@Matthias In my detailed answer I have added an answer to your last question.

Good first attempt. The circuit topology allows lots of exploration. Allow me to map the elements of
$$
x''(t)=-x(t)
$$into the circuit in Figure 2 using the analog computer elements in Figure 1. System simulations use integration rather than differentiation because the later are often unstable and noisy.
The equation can be twice integrated to use the analogue computer integrator elements. This 2nd order homogeneous equation has a zero input, so a place for a zero input is included in Figure 2 to show another analog computer element, the summing amplifier also shown in Figure 1. The operational amplifier configurations are inverting.

The circuit diagram in Figure 2 shows a state-variable configuration that can be used as an analogy for the equation. The circuit contains two (free) integrators in cascade so the input to each integrator is the derivative of the associated output. The summing amplifier provides feedback and a place for the zero-input. The task is to select element values to create that electrical analogue of the equation. The plot of \$v_{c}(t)\$ is a nice stable sinusoid at 1Hz. The only change from the OP's circuit is capacitor \$C_{2}\$ has an initial voltage, indicated by IC=1 above \$C_{2}\$.

First allow \$R_{1}=R_{2}=R\$ and \$C_{1}=C_{2}=C\$, then define:
$$
v_{c}(t)=x(t)\text{.}
$$
This then assigns one of the equation's state-variables to the output of the amplifier which is also the voltage across \$C_{3}\$. So then,
$$
v_{b}(t)=-RCv_{c}'(t)\text{ and }
$$
$$
v_{a}(t)=\left(RC\right)^{2}v_c^{''}(t)\text{.}
$$
So \$v_{a}(t)\$ can also be found through the feedback path and the summing amplifier,
$$
v_{a}(t)=\left(\frac{R_{3}}{R_{7}}v_{in}-\frac{R_{3}}{R_{4}}v_{c}\right)\text{.}
$$
Since \$v_{in}=0\$,** then,
$$  
v_{a}(t)=-\frac{R_{3}}{R_{4}}v_{c}\text{.}
$$
So now the equation is evident, except for two constants:
$$
\left(RC\right)^{2}v^{''}_c(t)=-Av_{c}\text{,}
$$
where \$A=\frac{R_{3}}{R_{4}}\$.
Substituting \$x(t)\$ and rearranging:
$$
x^{''}(t)=\frac{-A}{\left(RC\right)^{2}}x(t)
$$
shows the desired equation if \$A=\left(RC\right)^{2}\$.
Resorting to Laplace with the natural frequency \$\omega_{n}^{2}=\frac{A}{\left(RC\right)^{2}}\$:
$$
x^{''}(t)=\omega_{n}^{2}x(t)
$$
becomes
$$\left(s^{2}+\omega_{n}^{2}\right)X(s)=sx_{0}+x'_{0}\text{ ,}
$$
revealing two initial conditions \$x_{0}=x(0)\$ and \$x'_{0}=x'(0)\$.
Then back to time domain with
$$
x(t)=x_{0}\cos(\omega_{n}t)+\frac{x'_{0}}{\omega_{n}}\sin(\omega_{n}t)\text{.}
$$
This reveals that the actual frequency \$\omega=\omega_{n}\$, the natural frequency.
then matching with circuit values and setting \$\omega_{n}=1\$ yields
$$
v_{c}(t)=V_{0c}\cos t+V_{0b}\sin t=V_{c}\cos\left(t+\phi\right)
$$
as the solution to
$$
x^{''}(t)=-x(t)\text{,}
$$
where the amplitude
$$
V_{c}=\sqrt{V_{0c}^{2}+V_{0b}^{2}}
$$
and the phase
$$
\phi=\tan^{-1}\frac{-V_{0b}}{V_{0c}}
$$.
The initial constraints from the OP are
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
x'(t)=y(t)\\
y'(t)=-x(t)
\end{array}\right\}
$$
are shown to be satisfied if
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
-v_{b}(t)=y(t)\\
y'(t)=v_{c}(t)
\end{array}\right\} \text{.}
$$
**\$V_{in}\$ is negative in the diagram to implement the subtraction. It can also be applied to the non-inverting input but its gain is more complicated.

What is the soundest way to have this enter a stable mode in which it oscillates indefinitely at the solution of the differential equation?

Be careful using the word "stable". In system-theory, stable means that all transients die out. A system is marginally stable if there is a constant amplitude sinusoid at the output. I think that the stability your referring to is the stability of the signal not necessarily the system.
The circuit is already stable and looks to be sinusoidally stable in the simulation.
But wait! Let's let the simulation run for 10,000 seconds with out any configuration change.

Figure 2a shows that the amplitude is slowly decreasing. The system is inherently “slightly stable” due to losses around the loop so the amplitude gradually decreases as can be seen in the 10,000 second plot. So clearly the circuit does not exactly “solve” the given equation. There is a small first order term that appears:
$$
x^{''}(t)+2\zeta_{loss}\omega_{n}x'(t)=-\omega_{n}^{2}x(t)\text{,}
$$
where \$\zeta_{loss}\$, the damping ratio, should be zero. The frequency of oscillation is now \$\omega=\omega_{n}\sqrt{1-\zeta_{loss}^{2}}\$. The initial conditions eventually are in the distant past so their influence is no longer reliable for maintaining the amplitude. The equation is accurate enough for many several cycles of operation, but not forever. A recent time amplitude reference is required.
Many oscillators are made by making the system unstable, then at some voltage a non-linearity is used to reduce the gain. However making an oscillator is not the task here. Adjusting the system so that the 2nd order nature of the equation is retained is the task.
An opposing 1st order term can be introduced using the method in Figure 3.
$$
x^{''}(t)+2\zeta_{loss}\omega_{n}x'(t)-a_{1}x'(t)=-\omega_{n}^{2}x(t)\text{,}
$$
where \$a_{1}\approx\frac{R_{3}}{R_{7}}\frac{R_{6}}{R_{5}+R_{6}}\$if \$R_{6}\ll R_{7}\$. Only a small fraction is required so the input to the summing amplifier is also gain reduced. With this modification the system can be made unstable.

This is fun for learning how it works, but there is no perfect spot. Environmental (temperature) changes will move the target. So then the output must be compared to a desired reference then the voltage divider (or its associated gain) is adjusted in response to the difference.
The examples shown in the comments use the self heating effects of a thermistor or incandescent lamp to perform the function.
Also, the output amplitude can be measured using a peak detector then comparing to a local reference to control correcting feedback. However done, the correction voltage is applied to the summing amplifier. A correction current can also be applied to an input node of either of the integrators.
When the system becomes unstable, the amplitude starts at the initial condition of \$v_{c}\$ then rises exponentially until saturation at \$V_{CC}\$. So in this case, \$V_{CC}\$ can be used to set the amplitude of the oscillation. I do not know if a chaotic attractor will work for a stable, very under damped, \$\zeta>0\$, system. However if it is unstable, \$\zeta<0\$, then you may have success. I mention this because the basic system is stable. The amplitude variation (in square brackets) based on
$$v_{c}(t)=\left[e^{-\zeta_{loss}\omega_{n}t}V_{c}\right]\cos\left(\omega t+\phi\right)
$$
is easy to obtain from the differential equation, stable or otherwise. The damping ratio can be measured using logarithmic decrement technique. The influence of the environment makes the amplitude variation chaotic.

My first instinct would be to at a potentiometer in series with R25 in the inverter to interactively create a smidgen of gain making up for the losses in the circuit, and fiddle with it until the circuit oscillates stably.

Don't do that. As shown all that will happen is the frequency will change.
The capacitor's initial conditions were not being set as required by the homogeneous equation. This can be done in several ways. One method, shown in Figure 3, is to apply a current limited start-up pulse after power-up, (the MOSFET). Notice that the the simulator's initial conditions (IC) are set to zero for both capacitors. The capacitor's voltage value at the end of the pulse is proportional to the pulse period. The current is limited to the op-amp current rating.
That should provide a basis to work from while retaining the analog computer"ness" of the system.

Give me a second to skim through this quickly... Just kidding! Seriously - this is extremely detailed and helpful. It'll help me with playing with this and other "computers."

Have fun @Matthias

Fascinating! ...

The problem is, with resistors, capacitors, inductors, and ideal amplifiers, one can create an oscillator by Barkhausen's
model, of an amplifier and feedback with a phase shift.
Unfortunately, if you want a  pure sine wave, the 'ideal amplifier'
won't work.   Those linear components generate coupled
linear equations (Kirchoff rules) and can be solved
by inverting a matrix.
The 'feedback' part, though, means that a matrix of your solution
has to  have an eigenvalue of exactly 'one' or the oscillation
grows or decays.   Feedback makes exponential behavior in
addition to oscillatory.
There are three common solutions:

square-triangle oscillator --
Allow the amplifier to clip
(saturate the output stage at its supply rails) and make a square
wave/triangle wave oscillator, then filter or distort with diodes
the triangle wave into a sine-like form.
Gain-modulate  -- Like the old HP oscillator design, make the oscillation grow but include an amplifier element that changes value according to the oscillation amplitude.   Hewlett and Packard's design used the square-law character of resistance of a tungsten filament heated by the oscillation, and modern designs use a JFET as a variable resistor in similar manner.  Your R24 could conceivably include a light bulb.
Digital synthesis  -- calculate the value you want, and make a polygon approximation to the sine wave, step by step according to a digital clock that isn't an undistorted sine.


There are two more "solutions": (a) Use a "Double-Integrator-Oscillator (DIO)" with different time constants (see my detailed answer) or (b) use a GIC-based oscillator that contains inherent bandpass filtering. In both cases good sinusoidal signals are available (THD<1%) without any additional amplitude regulation.

@LvW Alas, it is NOT true that 'DIO' is a different solution: that just makes the first op amp to saturate against a power rail the limit (and a source of distortion) on oscillation amplitude.   As long as the R-L-C and amplifier components are linear, they cannot generate any fixed voltage: that takes a CURVE that can intersect a line in two places, to establish a voltage reference.

Sorry, but I must admit that I did not get the message of your comment. In your contribution you have mentioned a "pure sinewave" - which is impossible to produce. In this context, you have listed "three common solutions" - and the 2nd one is the classical method based on an additional non-linear part for amplitude limiting (by the way: Of course, no "pure sinewave" is possible). The background of my comment is another method without any additional device for amplitude regulation - thats all. Do you know what happens when one integrator output reaches the power rail? It`s a surprising effect.

Your circuit is the classical Double-Integrator Oscillator (DIO). It works very well when it is designed acording to Barkhausens oscilllation condition which is "Loop gain=1" (in practice: slightly larger than one for a safe start of oscillation.) Normally, the shown circuit can fulfill this requirement automatically. For (nearly) ideal opamps the circuit should continously oscillate at wo=1/RC.
Recommendation 1: When you are interested in continuous oscillation the resistors should be selected smaller (perhaps by a factor of 10). Resistors in the 100k range are perhaps to close to the opamps input resistance (non-ideal behaviuour). Perhaps this is the reason for the observed damping of the oscillation signal.
Recommendation 2: Nearly all oscillator topologies require a nonlinear part (diode, FET, thermistor,...) for amplitude control (to avoid hard limiting/clipping).
The oscillator type under discussion does NOT need such a device when both integrator time constants are NOT equal. In this case, the oscillation frequency is simply wo=SQRT(1/T1*T2).
In this case, the integrator with the largst gain (smaller time constant) reaches the maximum amplitude at first - and the second one (still in the linear range) provides a filtered version of the signal with a pretty good quality.
Explanation: For simulation purposes, the supply voltages should also be switched on at t=0 (TRAN analysis in the time domain). This is important for a safe start of oscillation (switch-on transients give a start signal). Due to real opamp models the phase of the loop gain function will cross the 0deg-line at one single frequency only (very close but slightly below wo).
Only ideal (non-existing) integrators have a fixed 90deg phase shift. Therefore. the phase crossing will take place at a frequency for which the gain is still above 0dB - and the condition for a safe start of oscillation is ensured.
Answer to your question: : "What I get from it is a damped oscillation at the frequency 1/(2RC), so my question is: What is the soundest way to have this enter a stable mode in which it oscillates indefinitely at the solution of the differential equation?"
The reason for the decaying amplitudes of your oscillation is as follows:
It is a secondary effect - not typical for this kind of oscillator topology. This effect depends (a) on the selected integrator time constants (resp. the desired oscillation frequency) and (b) on the used opamps.
In your case, we have a pretty low oscillation frequency (app. 160 Hz) and - at the same time - a rather "good" (wideband) opamp. Therefore, the magnitude of the loop gain will cross the 0db line at a frequency where the corresponding phase has NOT yet crossed the 0 deg line. Hence, the oscillation criterion for the phase (0 deg) is fulfilled at a frequency wo where the loop gain is already below 0 dB (smaller than "1"). Exactly THIS effect is responsible for the decaying amplitudes.
What can be done for getting steady-state oscillations? We must slightly increase the phase shift within the loop in order to have a loop phase of zero deg at a frequency where the gain of the loop ist still (slightly) above 0 dB. This can easily be done with a capacitor across the feedback resistor (100k) of the inverter. This changes the inverter function to a first order lowpass. In your circuit, a capacitor in the order of 10pF will do the job (cut-off frequency wc=1/RC=1E6 rad/s, which app. 1000 times the oscillation frequency wo).
It should be added that the described effect will not occur for (a) much larger oscillation frequencies and/or (b) other "worse" amplifiers (e.g. LM741) with more parasitic phase shift at lower frequencies.
Finally - in both cases (with or without the phase correcting capacitor) the oscillation amplitudes will increase until they reach the supply rail with a small amount of clipping only. However, this clipping effect can be overcome using two different time constants (as mentioned before).
As mentioned above, the Barkhausen criterion (loop phase of 0 deg with loop gan > 0dB)is fulfilled and oscillation will start automatically caused by power switch-on transients - without the necessity to use initial conditiones for capacitors

Can you provide reference, calculation or simulation for why this Recommendation 2 is true?

"For simulation purposes, the supply voltages should also be switched on at t=0 (TRAN analysis in the time domain). This is important for a safe start of oscillation (switch-on transients give a start signal)" This may start the oscillator, but the amplitude is not well defined. A specific initial condition on either or both capacitors is required,

@RussellH - regarding your 1st comment: When you have access to Research Gate":
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342550625_DIO_why_does_it_oscillate

All right, thank you all for your responses. I think I have figured it out: My circuit (in the real world, not a simulation) has by now been swinging for quite some time at the frequency predicted by the model.
I think what happens was that I let my mathematical naivety get in the way, and I tried to set up a circuit that seemed simple, but did not take into account certain realities, such as: integrators only integrate positive (or negative) functions well within a short portion of the time constant RC.
So what I did was cranking the spring constant way up: the feedback resistor in the inverting adder is now 100k, and the input is 10 Ohm. With RC = 0.66 and a per-RC frequency of 16, I got a real-world frequency of 24 -- well in line with the actual measurements.
That's also why my Circuit Lab simulation was dampened - what I thought was an integral was in fact some kind of crooked nonlinear operator as the capacitors reached...how shall I put it...capacity.
As I am getting ready to hit "Send" it's still swinging happily. What a great learning toy that was! Next project: Lotka-Volterra, as soon as my signal multipliers arrive.
Edited to add:


Matthias - so you have learned that (a) ideal integrators do not exist - with the exception that ideal integration of a signal could be ossible at one single frequency only....and (b) that the shown circuit will, nevertheless, oscillate. That means: We do not need ideal integrators for the circuit to oscillate - the only requirement is to meet the oscillation criterion from Barkhausen (loop gain >0 dB with zero phase shift at one single frequency fo.)
